# Water is removed by distillation to speed up dehydration. Why would that not work for the dehydration of 4-methyl 2-pentanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I understand that due to LeChatelier's principle, the removal water forces the reaction to move forward and make more to get back to equilibrium. However, I'm not sure why this would not work for this dehydration.

Comment: You need catalytic acid to get the water to leave the 4-Me-2-pentanol before you remove it from the reaction mixture

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your reaction set up? What is the evidence that it doesn't work?

Comment: Also note that contrary to the wording of your question, removing water does not speed up dehydration. Rather, it slows down rehydration.

Answer (score 0):

Physical dehydration has nothing to do with chemical dehydration, which is a change, a loss of water on the molecular level.